# In a vscode snippet, is it possible to delete both open curly brace and close curly brace just by one key press?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, tabstop, vscode-snippets

I have this VSCode JavaScript snippet which is used to create an arrow function.

```
{
    "test1": {
        "scope": "javascript",
        "prefix": [
            "test1"
        ],
        "body": [
            "(${10:}) => ${20:{}${40:}${30:\\}}"
        ],
        "description": "test1"
    }
}
```

As you can see, I created separate tab stops for both the open curly brace and the close curly brace. This is because when there is only a single statement in the body of the arrow function, I don't want the curly braces and I have a chance to delete them. The problem is that, I have to delete them by pressing the <kbd>delete</kbd> key twice, since they are in different tab stop. See below image.

[image]

Is there a way to change the snippet so that when the tab stop is on `${20:{}`, after I press the <kbd>delete</kbd> key once, the matching close curly brace `${30:\}}` will also get deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
"test1": {
    "scope": "javascript",
    "prefix": [
        "test1"
    ],
    "body": [
        //"(${10:}) => ${20:{}$40${30:\\}}"
        "(${1:}) => ${2:{$3\\}}"
    ],
    "description": "test1"
},
```

Now the third tabstop $3 is inside the $2 placeholder.  If you want the `{}` just tab to the next tabstop $3.  If you don't want the $`{}` just delete them and tab to the last tabstop.  Then as always you will have to tab to accept what you wrote in the last tabstop.